# Using the shifting lemma to solve higher order differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the question to solve the ODE 
$$y^{(9)}-6y^{(8)}+9y^{(7)}=e^t+3e^{3t}$$

The part that I struggle with is I have $y=Ae^t+t^2Be^{(3t)}$, obviously I don't want to differentiate these 9 times, so my mark scheme says use the shifting lemma, but I don't really understand it.

My characteristic polynomial is $p^7(p-3)^2$ and the shifting lemma says $L(p)t^2Be^{(3t)}=e^{(3t)}(p+3)^7p^2t^2B=3e^{(3t)}$

This bit I follow, as it's multiplying my $t^2Be^{(3t)}$ by the characteristic polynomial but with +3 (Assuming this is because of the 3t?) But on the next line of working it says

$e^3t(p+3)^72B=3e^{(3t)}$

And I have absolutely no idea where the 2 in front of the B came from, all help would be appreciated

Comment: To put parentheses in powers you should use curly brackets like this: y^{(9)}.

Comment: this also applies to e^{3t} $\to e^{3t}$ perhaps?

Comment: Yeah sorry my formatting is terrible I'll sort it

Comment: Is your equation correct ? You have twice the 8th derivative  and it dosent correspond to your characteristic polynomial  you surely mean 7th derivative

Comment: No I just corrected it, must have accidentally changed it while I was editting

Answer (score 1):

$$y^{(9)}-6y^{(8)}+9y^{(7)}=e^t+3e^{3t}$$
Using operator $D=\frac {dy}{dt}$ we can write it as
$$D^7(D^2-6D+9)y=e^t+3e^{3t}$$
$$
\implies 
\begin{cases}
D^7(D^2-6D+9)y=e^t \\
D^7(D^2-6D+9)y=3e^{3t}
\end{cases}
$$
The $e^t$ part is easy lets focus on the $e^{3t}$ part

$$D^7(D^2-6D+9)y=3e^{3t}$$
using $y=(Bt^2e^{3t})$
$$D^7(D-3)^2(Bt^2e^{3t})=3e^{3t}$$
Apply shifting's lemma

$$e^{3t}(D+3)^7(D)^2t^2B=3e^{3t}$$
And $D^2t^2$ means simply diferentiating twice $t^2$
$$\implies D^2t^2B=\frac {d^2t^2B}{dt^2}=2B$$
Thats why you have that 2
$$e^{3t}(D+3)^72B=3e^{3t}$$
You only need to evaluate the term thats independant of D in $(D+3)^7$ 
Which is by  binomial theorem $C=1$
$$e^{3t}(D^7+c_1D^6+.....+c_6D+3^7)2B=3e^{3t}$$
$$e^{3t}2B \times 3^7=3e^{3t}$$
$$\implies B=\frac 1 {2\times 3^6}$$

For the A coeeficient in $Ae^t$ 
$$y^{(9)}-6y^{(8)}+9y^{(7)}=e^t$$
$$Ae^t-6Ae^t+9Ae^t=e^t$$
$$A-6A+9A=1 \implies A=\frac 14$$
Therefore
$$\boxed{y_p=\frac14e^t+\frac 1{2 \times3^6}t^2e^{3t}}$$

Comment: Huge thanks mate this is great

Comment: @MattSimpson you're welcom...hope it helped you